# Can't get if ... else statement to properly switch while using special characters ("⏶/⏷")

Tags: javascript, html

In short I'm using special characters for a part of my website, and can't figure out how to express them in a JavaScript if ... else statement, which currently evaluates the `if` to false when it should be (initially) true.

---

I'm trying to have a simple change of text for a button on a website, but the button has special text in it. The button states "About ⏶" and I'm trying to make it change to "About ⏷". I want the button to switch between these states whenever pushed, so I'm using a simple if ... else statement in a script at the top of the HTML. Code is below.

```
<script>
function funcAbout() {
  var button_text = document.getElementById("undernavbtn");

  console.log(button_text.innerHTML)

  if (button_text.innerHTML == "About ⏶") {
    button_text.innerHTML = "About &#9207;"
  } else {
    button_text.innerHTML = "About &#9206;"
  }
}
</script>

<div id="undernav">
            <button type="button" id="undernavbtn" onclick="funcAbout()">About &#9206;</button>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm misunderstanding how these special characters work in some manner or another, but I don't know how. I used the console.log to see what was coming up from `button_text.innerHTML` and I literally just copied and pasted that into the `if` segment of the if ... else statement. And yet, I find that the `if` is being evaluated as false, causing the `else` to run.

Comment: This code appears to "just work" in Firefox, and worked in IE11 after some persuasion (specifiying a unicode font for the button element was required). What browser is it not working in?

Comment: Perhaps a source file encoding issue? Try changing `"About ⏶"` to `"About \u23f6"` in the if test conditional to check. As posted the HTML needs to be saved in unicode format with the character encoding of the file specified within the HTML. The second version, using `\u23f6`, should work for source files saved as plain ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it with CSS class and not rely on the text

```js
function funcAbout() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("undernavbtn");
    btn.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```css
#undernavbtn span::after {
  content: " \25B2"; 
}

#undernavbtn.active span::after {
  content: " \25BC"; 
}
```

```html
<div id="undernav">
    <button type="button" id="undernavbtn" onclick="funcAbout()"> <span>About</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: @ThatGuy7 you did not have the issue with your code at the very first place. This solution is actually not technically different from what you had.