# Why isn't my css `content:` working in multiple browsers, and improving cross-browser compatibility in general

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I'm working on my first practice HTML/CSS project and have gotten to trying to make everything compatible across browsers. My code currently works on Firefox, IE, and Edge. It is only not working in Chrome. I have text in a button that should display an up and down arrow, switching when clicked. I'd love to know about increasing compatibility, but I'll keep it specific for now.

I originally asked about trying to get the desired up arrow changing to down arrow effect in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191039/cant-get-if-else-statement-to-properly-switch-while-using-special-character?noredirect=1#comment60018597_36191039), and the code I used is from the only answer there. Code and JSFiddle are below. The JSFiddle seems to perfectly replicate the issue - works fine in Firefox, not in Chrome.

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThatGuy7/1pxq7b5o/)

JavaScript:

```
function funcAbout() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("undernavbtn");
    btn.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="undernavbtn" onclick="funcAbout()"><span>Button</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
#undernavbtn span::after {
  content: " \23f6"; 
}

#undernavbtn.active span::after {
  content: " \23f7"; 
}
```

---

Any ideas on how I can change this code such that it shows up in multiple browsers?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Dont use `::after`, use `:after`, that may fix your problem.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel this issue was last present with IE8, all newer browser support `::` selectors properly. Especially if it's not working in chrome, where this feature is supported since its beginning.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel, I don't think that's helped, but I did notice that I made an error with my assessment. The content is actually only not showing up in Chrome. It works in Firefox, IE, and Edge. I'll update my OP with correct information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because not every font has every character in their glyph set. Also not every browser uses the same default font family. For instance Chrome, at least on my Windows 10 OS, defaults to *Times New Roman*, *Arial*, *Consolas*. While Firefox defaults to *Segoe UI Symbol* and *Tahoma*, at least for the UI interface elements.

One way to make it so the character is visible in the most browsers is to use a font family you know includes that glyph. So for instance since *Segoe UI Symbol* includes the arrows you could do

```
#undernavbtn.active span::after {
  content: " \23f7"; 
  font-family:Segoe UI Symbol;
}
```

Demo

```js
function funcAbout() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("undernavbtn");
    btn.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```css
#undernavbtn span::after {
  content: " \23f6"; 
  font-family:Segoe UI Symbol;
}
    
#undernavbtn.active span::after {
  content: " \23f7"; 
  font-family:Segoe UI Symbol;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="undernavbtn" onclick="funcAbout()"><span>Button</span></button>
```

Of course this will not work if the user does not have the font installed. So you may have to use a [font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) rule that uses a font file (like woff2 font format) like how you use Google Fonts.

Comment: Segoe UI Symbol fixes it only for windows (I'm guessing). I have tried your example with Chrome on OS X, the issue still persists. For real world usage, I would suggest using something like glyphicons from bootstrap or font awesome, where they provide an actual font supporting the special characters. Plus, it looks very nice.

Answer (score 0):

This must be some kind of character encoding issue. I've tried it in the UTF-8 tool and it displays inside firefox, but not in chrome. [Here is the link](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=23f6&mode=hex) if you want to test it yourself.

Not sure why you've decided on this specific character, but since you say it's your first HTML and CSS practice, I'd say it probably doesn't matter, just pick another character.

Although this is an interesting issue, it might even be a bug within chrome, but I suggest making more thorough research before making such a claim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There's still a lot I don't know about character encoding, so I'm pretty clueless on this matter. As far as picking this character, this just seemed to be the best of the upward and downward arrows/triangles. What would I need to look for in another character to make sure it works in Chrome as well as other browsers? Am I looking for a different encoding type, or is the problem specific to the characters I've chosen?

Comment: @ThatGuy7 not sure what you should use. I have never done that with default fonts, usually I've used glyphs from bootstrap or font awesome, where they provide the custom fonts for these characters to ensure they work cross-browser.